# Does flutter or java backend have libraries or frameworks to interact with Metamask extension?

Tags: java, flutter, ethereum, metamask

I am currently building decentralized app using flutter for my front end and java springboot for my backend and database management. So I am curious if anyone knows if there are libraries or framework that allows flutter front end or java backend to interact with metamask extension? this is so that the users can approve transactions using their metamask wallet

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve on this question.

Comment: Hi there, I'm on similar route, appreciate if you could share your experiences. Did you have any write ups about your DApps development? I just wrote a post regarding my experiences so far at https://limcheekin.medium.com/closing-the-gap-a7a603dfdb2c. Hope to hear from you soon! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Web3j](https://github.com/web3j/web3j) for Java.

[Web3dart](https://pub.dev/packages/web3dart) for Flutter.

See also [WalletConnect mobile linking](https://docs.walletconnect.org/mobile-linking) to interact with wallets fro mobile applications like Flutter ones.